# Call init() function in .h file

Tags: c++, c++11, header-files

I would like to be able to call an `init()` function from an included `.h` file in another `.h` file, something like the following:

T1.h:

```
#ifndef T1_H
#define T1_H

class T1 {
   static void init() {...}
   ...
};
#endif
```

T2.h:

```
#ifndef T2_H
#define T2_H

#include "T1.h"

class T2 {
   ...
};

T1::init();
#endif
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want `T1::init()` getting called as many times as `T2.h` is #included somewhere? Why does the call have to be in the header? What is the ultimate goal of the exercise? Looks like [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me.

Comment: See if your compiler supports `#pragma startup`. If so, you can call `init()` in a standalone function that `#pragma` calls at program start.  Otherwise, you can call `init()` in the constructor of a static class/struct variable that is declared in T2.h (preferably in T2.cpp would be better).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The header include guards should prevent it from being called more than once.  I'm modifying a header-only library and the function registers it with the library.

Comment: @agg212: You misunderstand what header guards are. They only prevent the header from being processed multiple times within a single translation unit.  They do not prevent the header from being processed multiple times in the project as a whole. You can have multiple .cpp files (in)directly include T2.h and it will thus be re-processed each time, thus calling `init()` multiple times. For what you are attempting, it sounds like you need a singleton that has to be called at program startup to register everything you need.

Comment: Well, you could do something like this: `static const int ignore_me = (T1::init(), 0);` Note that `T1::init()` will in fact be called once for every source file that includes `T2.h`; design it accordingly. See also: [nifty counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik @RemyLebeau: As I said, it will be used internally in a header-only library, which means no `.cpp` files for multiple reprocessing.  Still, I check to make sure that the same variables are not initialized twice.

Comment: Well, *someone* will eventually #include those headers, right? The library may be header-only, but the program that uses the library isn't.

Comment: Until now I didn't even think it was legal to call a method in a header like that. Nevertheless, it still looks like a bad idea to me. Could you not call `T1::init()` within the constructor (or some other init method) of T2 and add some logic to T1 to ensure it isn't actually initialized more than once?